# Uninstall apache2 when apt-get claims it's not installed?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, apache-httpd

I restarted the VPS today only to find out that Nginx refused to start. As it turns out, Apache2 was running on the server already. Naturally, I stopped it and started Nginx, but I never installed Apache2. So I tried uninstalling it with `apt-get remove apache2`, but I only get met with

> Package 'apache2' is not installed, so not removed

Purge does nothing as well. What's going on? How can I get rid of apache2?

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep apache`?

Comment: @SailorCire apache2-mpm-prefork, ...-utils, ...-bin, ...-common and libapache2-mod-php5 all followed by "install". I'm guessing I need to uninstall those instead.

Comment: As a guess, I would start with `apache2-bin` and the others should be pulled as dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Apache 2 on debian is a stack of packages.

In wheezy (what I expect the asker was using based on the question date) the package "apache2" is just a dependency package. The actual apache2 binary is provided by the "apache2-mpm-*" packages while the init script is provided by the "apache2.2-common" package. The mpm packages depend on "apache2.2-common" so removing apache2.2-common should succeed is removing the stack of apache packages on a wheezy system.

In jessie the structure changed. "apache2" now provides the init script, systemd unit and configuration for the global apache instance. Removing it will stop the system starting apache but it won't actually remove the apache binaries. "apache2-bin" contains the actual binaries while "apache2-data" contains data files needed by apache.